# Retrieve Files From Device in Bootloader

Tags: adb, factory-reset, bootloader

I'm working on an android application. I accidentally turned on a developer option(I'm guessing RTL Layout), and now I get the message "..System UI has stopped working". I tried to clear the cache partition in recovery mode and that did nothing. I don't mind doing a factory reset but I just want to get files off the phone as I don't believe a backup. (My phone is the Droid Turbo if that matters)
When I connect it to my computer via USB it is not recognized. I believe it was set as PTP connection on my phone. It does not show up when I run `adb devices`. However in recovery mode, when I choose "apply update from ADB" it shows up when I run `adb devices`(with the word sideload next to it), but I cannot seem to find it in the device manager. I tried to pull/backup through adb but I get "error: closed". Is there any way to retrieve my photos/etc before/after I factory reset. Thanks!

Comment: Your "error closed" is probably because your adb.exe file is out of date on your computer. Now, as far as the bootloader is concerned. No you cannot pull files from the bootloader simply because it is not an advanced program. The work needs to be done from recovery.

Answer (score -1):

Did u tried to boot phone to fastboot mode, on my phone I do that this way:
 Pull out battery for 5 sec, put battery back, an then hold power + volume down key.
Than u can try using pull command.
What device do you have?

Comment: [tag:adb] commands won't work. ADB daemon doesn't run when the device is in fastboot mode.

Comment: Did you tried typing adb fastboot pull *path of what do you want to get* ? For me - worked fine. Bit u need to instal drivers for your phone if you didn't..

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your point. In my ADB client v1.0.32 there is no parameter named fastboot so the command `adb fastboot pull` doesn't exist for me. Could you shed some light here?

Comment: Whoops, i've mixed some things and missunderstand your question my bad..